# how can i create dbgrid with composite columns?

Tags: delphi, dbgrid

how can i create dbgrid with composite columns,

example :dbgrid header
|   name       |
| first | last |

Comment: Sorry, but it is not clear. Are you looking for nested column titles ?

Answer (score 2):

The composition should/has to be done on the dataset (table).
If you use a SQL Selects for getting your data, you shoud make the "composition" in the select statement (syntax depends of the data engine/sql server).
You can also make a calculated field on the datasset (look in help and in the examples installed with delphi.

Comment: thanks a lot
but i am not trying to make (lookup or calculated ) field, i want simply to see fields (columns) grouped by major titles, to be well presented in the dbgrid.
example
Columns  first name ,last name,sex..with "person" title
Columns job,salary,...with "professional" title

Answer (score 0):

Standard Delphi DBGrid does not support such feature except for Aggregate field type which is supported only in ClientDataset.

You can use 3rd-party grid components that provide such functionality. I personally like [EhLib](http://www.ehlib.com/) grid which provides this feature, and lots of other ones. Here is a screenshot of [EhLib](http://www.ehlib.com/) with nested column headers:

[image]
<sub>(source: [ehlib.com](http://www.ehlib.com/IMAGES/dbgridehform2.png))</sub>

You can see other screenshots in this link: 
http://www.ehlib.com/dbgrideh1.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can get such functionality by coding:

1. Subclassing a DBGrid
2. [Virtual TreeView](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=12&Itemid=33) you write the DB access stuff (there are examples on the site), and manage the custom drawing

Or by paying:

1. [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExQuantumGrid/) is my choice, amazing grids.
2. Any other third party grid like the one mentioned EHLib...